# Issues with OOP data setting __construct and SQL Joins with multiple classes

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, constructor

So here's the case:

I have two classes = Users and Blogs

The Blogs Class extends the Users Class

The Users class construct looks somewhat like this:

```
public $users_id;
public $users_blogs_id;
public $users_first_name;
public $users_last_name;

/**
 * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
 *
 * @param assoc The property values
 */

public function __construct($data=array()){

    if(isset($data['users_id']))
  {
   $this->users_id= $data['users_id'];
  }
if(isset($data['users_blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->users_blogs_id= $data['users_blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['users_first_name']))
  {
   $this->users_first_name = $data['users_first_name'];
  }
   if(isset($data['users_last_name']))
  {
   $this->users_last_name = $data['users_last_name'];
  }

}
```

And the Blogs Class constructor looks like this:

```
public $blogs_id;
public $blogs_title;
public $blogs_author;

/**
 * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
 *
 * @param assoc The property values
 */

public function __construct($data=array()){

    if(isset($data['blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->blogs_id= $data['blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_title']))
  {
   $this->blogs_title = $data['blogs_title'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_author']))
  {
   $this->blogs_author = $data['blogs_author'];
  }

}
```

The columns from which the tables are to be joined are "users_blogs_id" from the User Table and "blogs_id" from the Blogs Table.

My sql statement looks somewhat like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN blogs ON users.users_blogs_id = blogs.blogs_id";
$data = Users::select_all($sql);
```

Now the "select all" function is supposed to create a new object which will run the constructor and store the found values in its respective properties and then return the results back.

The issue with this is, if I call the Users Classes select, it'll only run the Users constructor and send me only the Users class properties with the found result. However, if I call the Blogs Classes select, it will return the blogs properties aswell as the users properties, but, only the blogs properties will contain the found results, the users properties will be empty since the blogs constructor does not include the set of code needed in order to set the users properties with the found result.

*Things that I've tried:*

**Creating Multiple Queries**

For example when I call the user select from the Users Class, I take the "users_blogs_id" columns value and then run another query that selects the blog from the Blogs Table Where "blogs_id = :users_blogs_id".

**Copying part of the Blogs / Users Constructor Codes**

So since part of the constructor codes are missing from the Blogs Class's Constructor, I just copy that part of the code from the Users Class's Constructor and paste it in the Blogs Class like this:

```
/**
 * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
 *
 * @param assoc The property values
 */

public function __construct($data=array()){

    if(isset($data['blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->blogs_id= $data['blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_title']))
  {
   $this->blogs_title = $data['blogs_title'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_author']))
  {
   $this->blogs_author = $data['blogs_author'];
  }

/*-----------------------From Users Class----------------------*/
if(isset($data['users_id']))
  {
   $this->users_id= $data['users_id'];
  }
if(isset($data['users_blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->users_blogs_id= $data['users_blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['users_first_name']))
  {
   $this->users_first_name = $data['users_first_name'];
  }
   if(isset($data['users_last_name']))
  {
   $this->users_last_name = $data['users_last_name'];
  }


}
```

This will set both the users class's and blogs class's properties with the found result from the select function but it just ends up with me repeating the codes which is something that I don't want aswell.

**Adding only the columns that are to be joined in the constructor**

The columns that I wanna join in this case are the "users_blogs_id" from the Users Class with the "blogs_id" from the Blogs Class.

Since the Blogs Class is the child class, I add the "users_blogs_id" construct code from the Users Class to the Blogs Construct Code like this:

```
/**
 * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
 *
 * @param assoc The property values
 */

public function __construct($data=array()){

    if(isset($data['blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->blogs_id= $data['blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_title']))
  {
   $this->blogs_title = $data['blogs_title'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_author']))
  {
   $this->blogs_author = $data['blogs_author'];
  }

/*--------------------Column that I wanna join----------------------*/
if(isset($data['users_blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->users_blogs_id= $data['users_blogs_id'];
  }


}
```

However this just ends up with me creating multiple sql queries which is something that I wanna avoid.

**Using Traits (The wrong way)**

So what I did was create a trait which has all the construct codes for all classes. Here's an example:

```
trait ConstructFunctions{
    
    
    
    public function __construct($data=array())
    {
     /*---------------Blogs Construct--------------------*/
      if(isset($data['blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->blogs_id= $data['blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_title']))
  {
   $this->blogs_title = $data['blogs_title'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_author']))
  {
   $this->blogs_author = $data['blogs_author'];
  }

/*-----------------------Users Construct------------------------*/

 if(isset($data['users_id']))
  {
   $this->users_id= $data['users_id'];
  }
if(isset($data['users_blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->users_blogs_id= $data['users_blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['users_first_name']))
  {
   $this->users_first_name = $data['users_first_name'];
  }
   if(isset($data['users_last_name']))
  {
   $this->users_last_name = $data['users_last_name'];
  }

    }

}
```

Then I simply call the trait in lets say the Blogs Class like this:

```
public $blogs_id;
public $blogs_title;
public $blogs_author;

/**
 * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
 *
 * @param assoc The property values
 */

public function __construct($data=array()){

    use ConstructFunctions;

}
```

Now this way worked the best for me. It got rid of the repetition of codes and it allowed me to pass a single sql query. However the issue is this is a wrong practice of constructors according to my colleagues and they have refrained me from using this method.

*My Objective*

To store and get all the class's property values with a single sql query using joins. To stop the repetition of codes in the constructor or atleast lessen it to an extent. To not break the laws of the constructors.

Every input is appreciated. Thank you. Do let me know if you have any queries regarding my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can call parent constructor :

```
// blog class
public function __construct($data=array())
{
    /* your code to set properties in blog */

    parent::__construct($data);
}
```

[demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bbe92d24732dae2c7c5ba1008a7b796e8e25baae)

But I would advise you instead to use [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and rethink your class design such as a class -> an entity -> a table :

```
class User // <---------------+
{                          // |
    // some fields            |
}                          // |
                           // |
class Blog                 // |
{                          // |
    // some fields            |
                           // |
    User $user;   // ---------+
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you @Cid for solving my question. I'll post the solution that I came up with for anyone who needs it:

The Blogs class has 2 simple changes: An additional property and the code to set the propertys value

```
public $blogs_id;
public $blogs_title;
public $blogs_author;

//New Property
public $users;

/**
 * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
 *
 * @param assoc The property values
 */

public function __construct($data=array()){

    if(isset($data['blogs_id']))
  {
   $this->blogs_id= $data['blogs_id'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_title']))
  {
   $this->blogs_title = $data['blogs_title'];
  }
   if(isset($data['blogs_author']))
  {
   $this->blogs_author = $data['blogs_author'];
  }

//New property setting code

   $this->users = new Users($data);
  

}
```

The sql remains the same however, the select statement is now called from the Blogs Class

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN blogs ON users.users_blogs_id = blogs.blogs_id";
$data = Blogs::select_all($sql);
```

It will now set the Blogs Class's properties with the found values using its constructor and also create a new Users object that will set the Users Class's properties with the found values using the Users Class's constructor, store it in the "$users" property located in the Blogs Class and then send back all the Blogs and Users properties with the appropriate data to the "$data" variable.